# For loop / error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to do a for loop to take the length of a dictionary according to a list values. I am obtaining the following error:

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Here is my code:

```
import random 



  ops_machine = {
    'OP1' : {'W1':5, 'w3':6, 'w4':7, 'w5':9},
    'OP2' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
    'OP3' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
    'OP4' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},

}


lsta = ['OP1', 'OP3', 'OP4', 'OP5']

individual = [0.21280838, 0.6381886,  0.83189561, 0.37306277, 0.41580845, 0.32058659,
 0.86574121, 0.11232781, 0.79238622, 0.81542997, 0.39082755, 0.20727362,
 0.4521442 , 0.850183 ,  0.76849343, 0.54011742, 0.27670335, 0.96537274,
 0.04313256, 0.44680338]


for i in lsta:
    for j in individual[3:7]:
        b = j * (len(ops_machine.get(i))-1)
        print(b)
```

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'OP3' doesn't exist in ops_machine, so ops_machine.get('OP3') returns None, so you get that exception when you try to call len() on it.

Comment: get(i) returns `None` when the key from `lsta` isn't in `ops_machine`.  You need to handle this in some way, but what way depends on how you expect it to behave which I don't know.

Comment: Hello Remco. Thak you for replying me. I added OP3 and OP4 but I am still having the same error. What it could be? I edited my post with all OPs

Comment: Now 'OP5' exists in `lsta` but is not a key of `ops_machine`.

Comment: Oh, yes! You have reason, I was not figuring out that. Now it worked!! Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

When i is 'OP3', 'OP4' or 'OP5' `ops_machine.get(i)` gives you None object and you get the error since `len()` function cannot be used with None type object. A possible solution could be checking the result of `ops_machine.get(i)` and if it is 0 set the length to zero.

```
import random 

ops_machine = {
    'OP1' : {'W1':5, 'w3':6, 'w4':7, 'w5':9},
    'OP2' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
}

lsta = ['OP1', 'OP3', 'OP4', 'OP5']

individual = [0.21280838, 0.6381886,  0.83189561, 0.37306277, 0.41580845, 0.32058659,
 0.86574121, 0.11232781, 0.79238622, 0.81542997, 0.39082755, 0.20727362,
 0.4521442 , 0.850183 ,  0.76849343, 0.54011742, 0.27670335, 0.96537274,
 0.04313256, 0.44680338]


for i in lsta:
    for j in individual[3:7]:
        values = ops_machine.get(i)
        if values is not None:
            values_len = len(values)
        else:
            values_len = 0 
        b = j * (values_len-1)
        print(b)
```

You may set b's to -1 if values is None type as an alternative way

```
import random 

ops_machine = {
    'OP1' : {'W1':5, 'w3':6, 'w4':7, 'w5':9},
    'OP2' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
}

lsta = ['OP1', 'OP3', 'OP4', 'OP5']

individual = [0.21280838, 0.6381886,  0.83189561, 0.37306277, 0.41580845, 0.32058659,
 0.86574121, 0.11232781, 0.79238622, 0.81542997, 0.39082755, 0.20727362,
 0.4521442 , 0.850183 ,  0.76849343, 0.54011742, 0.27670335, 0.96537274,
 0.04313256, 0.44680338]


for i in lsta:
    for j in individual[3:7]:
        values = ops_machine.get(i)
        if values is not None:
            values_len = len(values)
            b = j * (values_len-1)
        else:
            b = -1

        print(b)
```